# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Azure Webjobs SDK adding project reference throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-webjobssdk, .net-core-2.0

now that asp.net core 2.0 is here I started to test out the new azure webjobs sdk. Everything works fine but when I Add a project reference (netstandard 2.0 class library) I get this exception.[image: webjobs exception]

Stack Trace:

> System.MissingMethodException occurred
>     HResult=0x80131513
>     Message=Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.Object> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder.get_Properties()'.
>     Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
>     StackTrace:
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.GetFileProvider(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource.EnsureDefaults(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.ConfigurationUtility.BuildConfiguration()
>      at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>      at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.ConfigurationUtility.get_Configuration()
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.ConfigurationUtility.GetSettingFromConfigOrEnvironment(String settingName)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHostConfiguration..ctor(String dashboardAndStorageConnectionString)
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHostConfiguration..ctor()
>      at CommunicationsProcessor.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\RugerTek\Documents\Projects\facturas\CommunicationsProcessor\Program.cs:line 13

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also tested it on my side. But I can't reproduce the issue. Here are the steps what I did.

Step 1, Create a .NET Core 2.0 Console Application.
Step 2, Install Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0-beta1-10941 using following command.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs -Version 3.0.0-beta1-10941
```

Step 3, Add 2 classes to the project.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsDashboard", "mystorage-connectionstring");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage", "mystorage-connectionstring");
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}

public class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Step 4, Create a .NET Standard 2 class library named ALibrary. There is a only a simple type in my class library.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Step 5, Add reference to the class library.

[image]

Step 6, Build and run my console application(WebJob). I can get the right output from the console window if I add a message to the queue.

[image]

Please compare the steps between mine and yours and post the differences if they are.